# Mobile Responsive - Content Break

Tags: html, css

[content only takes 1/3 of it's while size, do you have any tips or any suggestions on how to make this take it's whole width? I did also put a width of 100% but still doesnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNdWL.png)

Comment: please do share some code as well.

Comment: We need to see the code in order to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the element you are trying to make 100% is within another element with a set width?

Example:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:700px">

       <div id="child" style="width:100%"></div> /* the width of the "child" is 700px due to the constraint of the parent*/

     </div>
```